# C# regular expression to match the string "dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd"

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing c# custom sonarqube rules. I'm trying to match a string literal in the  code which is exactly like "dd/mm/yyyy".
I mean whenever developer used dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd it should catch..
 I need regular expression for this in c# to match the "dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd"

Comment: You have a bigger problem: Is 01/04/2018 January 4th or April 1st? How can you tell? Don't use strings for dates unless you really, really have to, and if you do, make sure not to allow ambiguous formats. Make your user use only a specific format such as ISO 8601 (`yyyy-MM-dd`).

Comment: Also, instead of using regular expressions to check if a string is a valid representation of a date, just use `DateTime.TryParseExact`. Much easier to write, read, and maintain.

Comment: Yep, regexes don't (easily) help you avoid e.g. 31st April or 29th February in non-leap years. Almost always better to parse to a `DateTime` (and then keep it in variables typed that way throughout the rest of its journey through your code)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Great point about non-leap years. 31/30 days is possible (though extremely cumbersome) to validate in a regular expression - but then again, even the simple `dd/mm/yyyy` with no further validation at all is cumbersome comparing to `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comments, you have a much bigger problem - your allowed formats are colliding - There is no way to distinguish between `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` if the day is lower than 13.

Also, validating date formats can easily be achieved using `DateTime.TryParseExact` so there really is no need to write a big, hard to read, hard to maintain regular expression for that.

Check out this demo program ([click to run](http://rextester.com/BWUAH95780)) I've written to illustrate what I mean:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] dates = {
            // Valid dates
            "01/02/2018", // January 2nd (mm/dd/yyyy)
            "04/01/2018", // January 4th (dd/mm/yyyy)
            "20/01/2018", // January 20th (dd/mm/yyyy)
            "01/21/2018", // January 21st (mm/dd/yyyy)
            "2018/01/14", // January 14th (yyyy/mm/dd)

            // Invalid dates
            "23/13/2018", 
            "not a date", 
            "2018/22/01",
            "1/1/18"
        };

        string[] formats = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy/MM/dd"};

        for(var i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
        {
            DateTime dateTime;

            if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dates[i], formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dateTime))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dates[i] + " is a valid date: "+ dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") );
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dates[i] + " is invalid.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
01/02/2018 is a valid date: 2018-02-01
04/01/2018 is a valid date: 2018-01-04 // Note: Wrong date! should be January 4th!
20/01/2018 is a valid date: 2018-01-20
01/21/2018 is a valid date: 2018-01-21
2018/01/14 is a valid date: 2018-01-14
23/13/2018 is invalid.
not a date is invalid.
2018/22/01 is invalid.
1/1/18 is invalid.
```

So, having written all that - the correct solution is to avoid string representation of datetime whenever possible, and if you really must allow that, you need to make sure you only allow a well defined set of formats that are not colliding each other - `dd/mm/yyyy` and `yyyy/mm/dd` are fine, if you want to add another option you can choose a different delimiter to help you correctly distinguish the values - `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm-dd-yyyy` can live together quite happily, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Tihs regex will work for YYYY/MM/DD and DD/MM/YYYY:

```
((?=\d{4})\d{4}|(?=[a-zA-Z]{3})[a-zA-Z]{3}|\d{2})((?=\/)\/|\-)((?=[0-9]{2})[0-9]{2}|(?=[0-9]{1,2})[0-9]{1,2}|[a-zA-Z]{3})((?=\/)\/|\-)((?=[0-9]{4})[0-9]{4}|(?=[0-9]{2})[0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{3})
```

---

[image: example check:]

Comment: Consider date '12/11/2018' which is 11th of December, 2018. As per the regex mentioned above, will it works exactly?

Comment: Or is it consider as 12th of November, 2018?

Comment: It will consider 12/11/2018

Comment: @BarrJ without any other information but this string: `12/11/2018` you can't possibly know, even as a human, if it's December 11th or November 12th.

Comment: Attached a photo :), though I agree the date for itself is a very confusing and complex one.